# Moq Verify method not working with ToList

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit, autofixture

I am fairly new to unit testing in C# and learning to use Moq. Below is the example of my problem with Moq `Verify()` method.

```
[Theory]
[AutoData]
public async Task WhenSomething_ThenSomething(IEnumerable<string> stringCollection)
{
        //Arange
        //Mock of the method used in Handle() that returns stringCollection.
        someMock.Setup(x => x.MethodReturningStringCollectionForHandler()).ReturnsAsync(stringCollection);
        var someList = stringCollection.ToList();

        //Act
        await handler.Handle(new SomeRequest(someId));

        //Assert
        //I want to verify if someMethod() inside handler was called once but with appropriate stringCollection
        problematicMock.Verify(x => x.someMethod(someList), Times.Once());
}
```

The above scenerio works, but when I remove `someList` variable and use `ToList()` directly in `Verify()`, like this:

```
problematicMock.Verify(x => x.someMethod(stringCollection.ToList()), Times.Once());
```

then I get the following exception:

```
Message: 
    Moq.MockException : 
    Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times: x => x.someMethod(["83436e1f-bd2f-44d3-9f8c-ba6afbf73e95", "16593c11-0959-4ebe-aafd-d5fbe0cfbd17", "633e6557-bed0-4ff0-b550-8790fab9e629"])
```

As one could imagine, this is quite problematic, what if `someMethod()` would accept many collection-type parameters? For this particular example I would have to create many variables to pass to `Verify()` method. Why does it work this way?

Comment: You're setting up `someMethod` with the parameter `someId`, but you're verifying it was called with `someList`. Is that correct? Please post a [mre].

Comment: Corrected the example, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You've made edits, but those edits make your code example less of a [mre]. I don't know now how `problematicMock` is setup, or what `handler.Handle` is. Please make the code that you post self-contained.

Comment: someList and a later stringCollection.ToList() are to different lists.They may contain exactly the same data but they are not the same List<T> instance.

Comment: @Ralf so how to verify just the data inside the collection and why it works for `someList` and not for `stringCollection.ToList()` even though the data are the same?

Comment: I assume Moq internally uses the IEquatable interface for comparing when its implemented. List<T> does not. So the thing Moq presumably does here is comparing the references (the memory address where the data is) and they aren't the same reference so Moq will say you did not call it with the same reference and barks. It might not even know that a list is involved. It just knows that it is an object that isn't comparable and the references are different.

Comment: For readibilty setup and verify of the mock should be in the same method. So using the same list  in both occurrences seems no problem to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short Moq compares `List<T>` instances on reference basis. The two `ToList` calls create two separate collections therefor their references are different.

In order to overcome of this you need to use `It.Is` inside your `Verify`

```
problematicMock.Verify(
    x => x.someMethod(
       It.Is<List<string>>(input => AssertCollection(stringCollection.ToList(), input))), 
    Times.Once());
```

- `It.Is` receives a `Func<List<string>, bool>` delegate
- `input` is the argument of the `someMethod` call

Here is a naive implementation of the `AssertCollection`:

```
public static bool AssertCollection(List<string> expected, List<string> actual)
{
    try
    {
        Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

If you pass `stringCollection.ToList()` as an expected value then it will pass, but if you pass
`stringCollection.Reverse.ToList()` or `stringCollection.Skip(1).ToList()` then it will fail.